# Machine Code Jump Destination Calculation

Tags: machine-code

Ok, so I need to hook a program, but to do this I am going to copy the instructions `E8 <Pointer to Byte Array that contains other code>`. The problem with this is, that when I assemble `Call 0x100` I get `E8 FD`, We know the E8 is the call instruction, so FD must be the destination, so how does the assembler take the destination from 0x100 into FD? Thanks, Bradley - Imcept

Comment: What is the target machine code? There's no way `E8FD` means `call 0x100`

Comment: I opened it up in  EMU8086, and yes, it means CALL 0x100. But, I may not know what I'm talking about.

Comment: What assembler are you using as well?

Comment: Flat Assembler, NetWide Assembler, and EMU8086 assemble it as the same thing.

Comment: E8 should take a 16-bit argument, so FD is only the first 8 bits. What's the second 8 bits?

Comment: The whole file is 'E8 FD 00', but when I compile 'call 0x999' I get 'E8 96 09'. So I'm guessing the first 8 bits is part of the destination, and  some kind of flag or setting encoded together, followed with another 8 bits that have the rest of the destination ?

Comment: Whatever reference told you that E8 is the call instruction should also have described how the jump target is calculated.

Comment: Sadly it did not, because I don't have any reference ATM, I was just learning this from assembling things then then hex editing them, to see how it is done. I just wasn't able to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://wwwcsif.cs.ucdavis.edu/~davis/50/8086 Opcodes.htm](http://wwwcsif.cs.ucdavis.edu/~davis/50/8086%20Opcodes.htm)
E8 is a 16 bit relative call. So for instance `E8 00 10` means call the address at the PC+0x1000.

Comment: I now see that its the offset from the current CS to the instruction pointer + 1

Answer (score 3):

There is plethora of jump/call opcodes and some of them are relative. I'd say you in fact got not `E8 FD` but `E8 FD FF`. `E8` seems to be "call 16-bit relative" and `0x100` is the place where instructions are placed by default.

So you put `call 0x100` at address 0x100, and the generated code is "do the jump instruction, and jump -3 from the actual instruction pointer". `-3` is because the shift is computed from the position *after* the instruction is read, which in case of `E8 FD FF` is 0x103. That is why the shift if `FD FF`, big-endian for `0xfffd`, which is 16-bit `-3`.

Comment: I'll wager that the actual opcodes were not `E8 FD FF`, because then you'd have an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, it could have been `E8 FD 00`, in what case the instruction was put at 0x00 address. Which seems to me a bit unusual, since my memory faintly tells me 0x100 should be the beginning of code in old DOS, but it could be 0x00 in this case. Original address of `call 0x100` wasn't specified, so I can only guess.